# Confused about a step of a proof using absolute continuity...

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory, absolute-continuity

I am trying to follow this proof that has F absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$ and $x$ is such that $F'(x)=0$ on a measurable subset $E$ of $[a,b]$ with measure of $E= b-a$. Anyways, here is the part that's confusing me.

Now let $E$ be the set of those $x \in (a, b)$ where $F'(x)$ exists and is zero. By our assumption $m(E) = b − a$. Next, momentarily fix $\epsilon > 0$. Since for each $x \in E$ we have $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}=0$ then for each $\eta > 0$ we have an open interval $I = (a_\eta, b_\eta) \subset [a, b]$ containing $x$, with $|F(b_\eta) − F(a_\eta)| \leq \epsilon(b_\eta − a_\eta)$ and $b_\eta − a_\eta < \eta$.

How is this possible? I thought given any $\epsilon$, there exists a $\delta$ such that $\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}<\epsilon$ if $|h|<\delta$. But here it says its true for any $\eta$.. How is this possible? Please someone explain. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Typing 'please help me' in the title of your question is not going to get more people to click on it, but rather the contrary...

Comment: I'm not sure what confuses you here. Maybe the following helps: The derivative is defined as the limit of difference quotients. If you take the difference quotient between two points $x$ and $x + h$ that are close enough (i.e. if $h$ is small enough), you can get the difference quotients arbitrarily close to the derivative. If you choose $ax = x$ and $bx = x + h$, do you see how one implies the other?

Comment: No because given any fixed epsilon, there is a delta small enough such that if h is less than delta, the difference quotient will be less than epsilon. But here it says for any delta basically this works..how does that even work, for a fixed epsilon you're not free to choose delta are you?Only for sizes of h smaller than delta this would work but not bigger. Thanks for the help

Comment: I can't tell what the question is.

Comment: How is it that for a fixed epsilon, the difference quotient will be less than epsilon FOR ANY delta instead of only those delta that are less than the delta you get from limit definition.

Comment: Can we clarify your question? In general, we would say *for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta >0$ such that etc.* Are you asking why the existential quantifier there can be changed to the universal?

Comment: @Socchi With all the quantifiers spelt out, what we have is (from the convergence of the difference quotient to the derivative, which is zero): For any ($\forall$) $\varepsilon > 0$, there is ($\exists$) a $\delta > 0$ such that whenever ($\forall$) $h < \delta$, then $\left| \frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}h \right| < \varepsilon$. Thus for any $\varepsilon > 0$ you have the interval $(a_\varepsilon, b_\varepsilon) = (x,x+\delta)$ that will do in the proof, and so will $(x,x+h)$ for any $h < \delta$.

Comment: Hi, thanks..that's the thing that shows its true for any h less than a specific delta or $\eta$ (which comes for a fixed epsilon), but it does  NOT show it holds for any $\eta$ positive which is what it says in the proof.. Do you see what I mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Now from the definition of the derivative at $x$ (which is zero), we get a $\delta > 0$ such for every $h < \delta$ we have
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
  \left| \frac{F(x+h) - F(x)}h \right| < 0
\end{equation}

Now to prove, based on (1), that for any $\eta > 0$ we can find an interval $(a_\eta,b_\eta)$ with $b_\eta - a_\eta < \eta$ and
$$
  \left| \frac{F(b_\eta) - F(a_\eta)}{b_\eta - a_\eta} \right| < 0\text.
$$

First consider the case $\eta \le \delta$. By the above, we can set $a_\eta = x$, $b_\eta = x + \eta/2$ and have (1) apply with $h = \eta/2 \le \delta/2 < \delta$ while $b_\eta - a_\eta = \eta/2 < \eta$.

Now consider the case $\eta > \delta$. This time, we set $a_\eta = x$, $b_\eta = x + \delta/2$. Again, (1) applies with $h = \delta/2 < \delta$ and we have $b_\eta - a_\eta = \delta/2 < \delta < \eta$.

Comment: If this does not answer your question, please let me know why it doesn't. If it does answer your question, please click the checkmark to the left to accept this answer.